# How should the backend code be if I want to give a part of a large amount of data and provide more and more as the frontend asks?

Tags: loopbackjs, graphql, bigdata

I'm currently using **loopbackjs** for making the API endpoints, and **graphQL** as an intermediate for making queries from the frontend, where I use **Relay and React** framework.
Now, I have an application where a **user** can view a **list of projects** (The **project** has very generic information like creation date, name, etc.). This list of projects can be very large. So its infeasible to just send all the projects at once. Now, I want to send the first few projects to the frontend and then as the user scrolls down, I want to send a part of the remaining projects when the user reaches the end of the list provided to him/her in the frontend.
I've thought about maintaining a pointer sort of a thing, that indicates till where I've fetched the projects in the list so that I know from where I would fetch the further projects. But this pointer is dependent on the user so for every user I need to maintain a pointer. This gets everything very messy.
Is there a clean approach for doing what I want with the current stack I am using?

Comment: Loopback.js has a solution for pagination using `skip` and `limit` filters.
I think it might be a good approach in terms of backend, which will require holding "pointer" on frontend (actually an increasing counter of number 'pages' fetched).  See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Skip+filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fetch my first 25 projects:

```
projects(first: 25, after: $lastID) {
  ...
}
```

You could probably change the either variables passed to graphql to return you the infinite scrolling of list of projects. First 25 already helps u limit the amount u get back.

For more references you could find it here https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html

Comment: I used the documentation for 'connections' and it had everything I wanted. This solved my problem! Thanks!